# CodeDeploy with VPC endpoint on private subnet instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-code-deploy, blue-green-deployment

I am trying to use CodeDeploy to deploy my revisions on private subnet instances using VPC endpoint.
VPC endpoint is having required subnet configured and security group applied on VPC endpoint is having all inbound and outbound allowed. Still my deployment is failing and I do not have any way to check logs on EC2 instance since it is private. Any help or guidance regarding this?
I am trying to follow the below link:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/aws-codedeploy-now-supports-deployments-to-virtual-private-cloud-endpoints/

Comment: If you have truly private VPC (no public subnets), you should be able to setup SSM Session Manager to login to the instances. This will require SSM role for the instances and SSM interface endpoints.

Comment: I have 2 private and 2 public subnets within my VPC.

Comment: If so you can launch a bastion host in a public subnet, and then ssh into it, and from there into your private instances to inspect them.